# Spring Batch Reader Performance issue

Tags: spring-batch

We have a Spring batch code that reads data from the local hard disk, creates an Object and send to Apache Solr for Indexing. We are seeing a very poor performance when using JBoss compared to when we run the code in standalone.

Using YourKit profiler, we see that the time consumed is for the component for reading data and creating solr objects.

For the times we have recorded, For 1000 records, standalone is taking 7 seconds where in JBoss as a batch process, it is taking 7 minutes.
/**
 *

```
 * Name : AccountingReader.java
 * Description: This class is used to read accounting source data from the flat files.
 * References : None
 */
```

public class AccountingReader implements ItemReader {
    /*logger*/
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountingReader.class);
    private final ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
    private Resource resource;
    private FlatFileItemReader reader;

`/**
 * Gets the input Resource[file] to read the data from
 *
 * @return the Resource[file] with input data
 *
 */
public Resource getResource() {
    return resource;
}

/**
 * Set the input Resource[file] to read the data from
 *
 * @param resource the Resource[file] with input data
 */
public void setResource(final Resource resource) {
    this.resource = resource;
}

/**
 * Method which maps read lines to Accounting object
 *
 * @return LineMapper the <code>LineMapper</code> object
 */
private LineMapper<Accounting> createAccountingLineMapper() {

    final DefaultLineMapper<Accounting> accountingLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<Accounting>();

    final LineTokenizer accountingLineTokenizer = createAccoutingLineTokenizer();
    accountingLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(accountingLineTokenizer);

    final FieldSetMapper<Accounting> accountingMapper = createAccountingMapper();
    accountingLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(accountingMapper);

    return accountingLineMapper;
}

/**
 * Method use to delimit field names in file set
 *
 * @return LineTokenizer the line tokenizer object containing the row and field delimiters
 */
private LineTokenizer createAccoutingLineTokenizer() {

    final DelimitedLineTokenizer accoutingLineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    //accoutingLineTokenizer.setDelimiter(Constants.FILE_ROW_SPLITTER1);
   accoutingLineTokenizer.setDelimiter(Constants.FILE_ROW_SPLITTER);
    accoutingLineTokenizer.setNames(Constants.ACCOUNTING_FIELDS.split(
            Constants.COMMA));



    return accoutingLineTokenizer;
}

/**
 * Method used to create Mapper based on the domain object
 *
 * @return the Mapper which is created based on the domain object [Accounting] targeted
 */
private FieldSetMapper<Accounting> createAccountingMapper() {
    final BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Accounting> accountingMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Accounting>();
    accountingMapper.setTargetType(Accounting.class);

    return accountingMapper;
}

/**
 * Reads the data line by line and set to Accounting object using the LineMapper created previously
 *
 * @return Accounting object produced by parsing each line
 * @throws ParseException
 * @throws UnexpectedInputException
 * @throws Exception exception while parsing the data input flat files
 */
//@Override
public Accounting read()
    throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException {
    Accounting accounting = null;
    logger.debug("Accounting read() - Starts");
    long start1= System.currentTimeMillis();
  // System.out.println("read:::::::::::::::starts"+start1);
    try {
        accounting = reader.read();
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
         logger.error(
                "Error is occured during reading the Accounting file " +
                ex.getMessage(), ex);
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    long end = (System.currentTimeMillis()-start1);
    logger.debug("Accounting read() - Ends in milli seconds"+end);
   // System.out.println("read:::::::::::::::ends"+end);
    return accounting;
}

/**
 * Sets FlatFileItemReader as the reader to read input flat file [resource]
 * Also the job start timestamp is set in the execution context.
 *
 * @param stepExecution  the <code>StepExecution</code> object
 */
@BeforeStep
public void beforeStep(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
    reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Accounting>();
    reader.setResource(resource);
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    reader.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

    final LineMapper<Accounting> accountingLineMapper = createAccountingLineMapper();
    reader.setLineMapper(accountingLineMapper);
    reader.open(executionContext);
    stepExecution.getExecutionContext()
                 .putString(Constants.STARTTIME,
        SolrUtils.getCurrentTimeStamp());

}`

The same code is taking less time when it is triggered as a stand alone. We have a plan to use the partition once the current issue is fixed to improve performance.

Sample for 10 records where it is taking time:
<37 calls> com.tms.incentives.batch.process.itemreader.AccountingReader.read() 90 9 10
java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.hasNext() LinkedHashMap.java 90 0 90 334267

Comment: Will spring batch version will have an impact on performance. for standalone, 3.0.2 was used and for app it is 2.1.8

Comment: Why do want to run the springbatch app inside a JEE container in the first place? spring offers everything you need (e.g. transaction management) there is no advantage to wrap the whole thing into a JEE container.